# How can i set a background image from my database?

Tags: laravel

image not retrieved as i called to be seen there is a problem calling the image it don't return anything .

```
<div class="content-wrap">
                            @forelse($newss->chunk(8) as $chunk)
                                @foreach($chunk as $news)
                                    <article class="blog-entry-travel animate-box">
                                        <div class="blog-img" style="background-image: {{url('images',$news->image)}}"></div>
                                        <div class="desc">
                                            <p class="meta">
                                                <span class="date">{{str_limit($news->created_at, $limit = 10, $end = '')}}</span>
                                                <span class="pos">By <a href="#">{{str_limit($news->journalists->name,$limit = 10,$end = '')}}</a></span>
                                            </p>
                                            <h2><a href="{{route('details')}}">{{str_limit($news->title,$limit = 50,$end = '')}}</a></h2>
                                            <p>{{str_limit($news->subject,$limit = 200,$end = '')}}</p>
                                            <p><a href="{{route('details')}}" class="btn btn-primary with-arrow">Read More <i class="icon-arrow-right22"></i></a></p>
                                        </div>
                                    </article>
                                @endforeach
                                @empty
                                    <h3>No News</h3>
                            @endforelse
                        </div>
```

Comment: `background-image: url(/images/{{ $news->image }});` if this doesn't work dd the url and check if its passing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He need to add a slash too

```
url('images/' . $news->image)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here `{{url('images',$news->image)}}` you used a comma to concatenate the URL.

**Try like this:**

```
style="background-image: {{url('images/' . $news->image)}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="slider-img" style="background-image: url('{{ asset('/storage/images/foods/'.$food->image) }}')"></div>
```

This worked for me